# Looking for the specific software used to create a diagram for code

Tags: git, diagram

I have seen the following image shared that is basically a diagram of code. It has a git icon in the menu, it has a code sign in the menu, so I assume it is mainly used for that purpose. Been looking for a while, but no clue. Reverse image search did not work too.

[image]

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, what is the code sign?  Are you only looking for this software?  If not, then you should spell out the requirements.

Comment: @RohitGupta It seems that I somehow decided to say 'code sign' and expect people to know what I think of. I was reffering to the `</>`. 
Anyways, turns out that the software I was looking for is called GooseCode.

Answer (score 0):

[GooseCode](https://apps.apple.com/gb/app/goosecode/id6447558563)

**Disclosure: I am the author of this app.**

GooseCode is designed to map and visualise code with a priority on reading code (as that’s the tricky part). Future versions will include IDE integrations so you can write in VSCode or IntelliJ and render dynamically.
I see you’ve already discovered it on your own and would love you to share your experiences.

Comment: Welcome Matt! Can you please add a link to your creation within your answer?  Thanks, and again, welcome!